# How to get a item in an object which is in another object

Tags: javascript, php, object

```
{
    "swift":
        {
            "type":"text",
            "value":"WF0987"
        },
    "routing_number":
        {
            "type":"text",
            "value":"8402984302"
        },
    "bank_address":
        {
            "type":"text",
            "value":"BullDog 57483, USA"
        },
    "purpose_of_transfer":
        {
            "type":"text",
            "value":"FAMILY SUPPORT"
        }
}
```

i have an obj inside another obj
i want to retrieve the value of each key

this is my solution

```
@foreach ($transfer->beneficiary->details as $key => $item)
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
        <span>
            ucFirst($key)
        </span>
        <span class="text--info font-weight-bold">
{{ $key()?['value'] }}
        </span>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

displaying the key works but not the value child

how should i do it so that it works??

Comment: `$key()?['value']` should be `$item['value']`

Comment: @Barmar i tried that but it didnot work...

Comment: Why don't you have `{{}}` around `ucFirst($key)`?

Comment: Are these arrays or objects? You're looping over the top-level object as an array. But if the elements are objects, it should be `$item->value`

Comment: it still work with or without ```{{ }}```

Comment: i thought objects are in ```{}``` and arrays are in```[]```, am i wrong??

Comment: When PHP parses JSON, it can return either associative arrays or objects, depending on the second argument to `json_decode()`.

Comment: PHP doesn't have object literals, so what you posted isn't PHP code. I assumed it's the original JSON.

Comment: bro it worked by using this ```{{ $item->value }}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me `{{ $item->value }}` thanks to @Barmar for his contribution

so this was my final code

```
    @if($transfer->beneficiary->details)
                                    @foreach ($transfer->beneficiary->details as $key => $item)
                                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
                                            <span>
                                                @lang(ucFirst($key))
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="text--info font-weight-bold">
                                                {{ $item->value }}
                                            </span>
                                        </li>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach ($transfer->beneficiary->details as $key => $item)
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
        <span>
            ucFirst($key)
        </span>
        <span class="text--info font-weight-bold">
            {{ $item['value'] }}
        </span>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

You can also use the `->` operator to access the value property like this: `{{ $item->value }}`